# Moving a precompiled sysimage to a new machine

Tags: julia, packagecompiler.jl

I have used PackageCompiler.jl to create a ".so" file of 3 precompiled packages in Julia. Can I send this .so file to someone for them to run, provided they have the right version of Julia installed? In addition, can I use the same .so file if I move to a new computer, provided that I install Julia?

Comment: Yes, if the packages within the sysimage are "relocatable", see e.g. the docs in PackageCompiler: https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/stable/apps.html#relocatability

Comment: Thank you @KristofferCarlsson, will look into creating a relocatable app.